# Jquery Validator doesnt validate once user comes back on page

Tags: jquery, validation

I have 2 forms. The user has to complete first form & then can go to second form Once the first form is submitted, the user goes to second form. The user can go back and change the first form. 
For validations of form, Jquery validator is used

The problem is when I go back to first form, the jquery validator always shows the first form to be valid even though I make some changes on the first form. I may enter wrong data, or make fields empty, still the first form is valid.

I tried multiple ways to retrigger the validator but it doesnt seem to work.

```
$("#formId").validate({
     cache:false,
     onsubmit: false,
     focusInvalid: true,
         rules: {
            name1: {
                required: true
            },
            dob:{
                required: true,
                date:true,
                maxDob: true,
                minDob: true
            }
            },
            messages: {
            name1:{ 
                required: "Please provide Patient's Name.",
                },
            dob:{ 
                required: "Please provide Patient's Date of Birth in the suggested format.",
                date:"Please enter a valid date.",
                maxDob:"Please enter a valid date.",
                minDob:"Please enter a valid date."
            }},
             errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if  (element.attr("name") == "gender" ){
                error.insertAfter("#message3");
            }}




$('#formId').click(function() { var validator = $( "#formId" ).validate(); validator.resetForm(); console.log($("#formId").valid()); if($("#formId").valid()){ $("#formId").submit(); validator.destroy();} else console.log("show errors"); });
```

Both are in document.ready

Comment: Show some code, so that it would be easy to help you out.

Comment: Not in the comment dude ! update your question instead.